# What happens to open source Glassfish by Oracle?

Tags: oracle, open-source, glassfish

As you know Sun/Glassfish has been captured by the Oracle and Oracle has commercial approach.
So, what do you think for the future of Open-Source Glassfish and/or Netbeans IDE?

Is this better choice to migrate to eclipse/Jboss or not yet?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens. Oracle has declared both products (as well as MySQL) will remain Open Sourced and actively developed.
GlassFish has now two versions: 'Open Source' edition and 'Oracle' edition, the latter being same as open source with addition of some plugins and support services.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Community Roadmap](http://glassfish.org) document is still appropriate knowing that since that GlassFish 3.0.1 has been released.